# eigendecomposition under linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Last comment: Currently, it seems that we don't know more efficiently way to compute the positive or negative eigenfactor for the sum of matrices even though we assume that we know all the eigenfactors for each matrix before the sum. The finite number of matrices under the sum are assumed to be real, symmetric matrices which are diagonalizable.

${A = A^T=VDV^T \; \; \; \; \;...(1)\\
A=A^{+}+A^{-} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; ...(2)\\
A^{+} = \sum_{\lambda_{i}>0}{\lambda_{i}{p}_{i}p_{i}^T}, 
\; \; \; \; \; \; ...(3)\\
A^{-} = \sum_{\lambda_{i}<0}{\lambda_{i}p_{i}p_{i}^T} 
\; \; \; \; \;  \; \;...(4)\\
\text{(1) is the diagonalization of real, symmetric matrices}\\
\; \; \; \; \; D\text{ is the diagonal matrix containing eigenvalues,}\\
\; \; \; \; \; V\text{ contains column vectors as associated 
eigenvectors to each eigenvalue } \lambda_{i}\\
\text{(2) is the factorization into positive and negative components
}\\
\; \; \; \; \; \text{following the definition in (3) and (4)}\\
\text{(3),(4) define the sum of positive eigenfactors and negative counterpart, 
}\\
\; \; \; \; \; p_{i} \;
\text{is the associated eigenvector for an eigenvalue } \lambda_{i}\\
}$

${
\text{Now, we're interested in taking the positive component as defined
in (2) and (3) above 
}\\
\text{but we do so on a sum of diagonalizable matrices.}\\
}$
${u \in C, u\text{ is nothing but natural-numbered index to tell }\\
\text{finite number of real, symmetric matrices.}}$

${
\bigg(\sum_{u \in C}{A_{u}}\bigg)^{+}=
\bigg(\sum_{u \in C}{\Big(A_{u}^{+}+A_{u}^{-}\Big)}\bigg)^{+}
 \; \; \; \; \;...(5)\\
=\bigg(\sum_{u \in C}{\Big(V_{u}^{+}D_{u}^{+}V_{u}^{T}
+V_{u}^{-}D_{u}^{-}V_{u}^{-T}\Big)}\bigg)^{+}
 \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;...(6)\\
=\bigg(\sum_{u \in C}{V_{u}^{+}D_{u}^{+}V_{u}^{+T}}
+\sum_{u \in C}{V_{u}^{-}D_{u}^{-}V_{u}^{-T}}\bigg)^{+}
 \; \; \; \; ...(7)
}$
${
\text{(5),(6),(7) are equivalent.}\\
\; \; \; \; \;
\text{Is there a way to get the positive eigenfactor after the sum
more efficiently}\\
\; \; \; \; \;\text{without taking the full eigendecomposition
after the sum to compute}\\
\; \; \; \; \;\text{the positive eigenfactor? We assume we know all the
eigendecomposition of each } A_{u}.
}$

Comment: Huh? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I don't think you succeeded in explaining yourself. Try again. For example: "(5)-(6)-(7) are what we already can tell"... **what**?

Comment: @copper.hat, is this question totally non-sense? I just wondered if there is some way to compute it more efficiently. (The question is modified)

Comment: I don't know. You need to explain what you want rather than just dumping stuff and hoping someone will figure it out.

Comment: Why don't you begin from the beginning: define stuff. For example, apparently $\;A_u\;$ is matrix. What is that $\;u\;$ there? (1) is *orthogonal* diagonalization of a real symmetric matrix (spectral theorem)...I guess. Remember: we don't read what you read, we cannot guess your notation...

Comment: @copper.hat. (5),(6),(7) are just equivalent but I wonder if there is a way to achieve the positive part after the whole sum more efficiently assuming we already know all the eigendecomposition of the matrices ${A_{u}}$.

Comment: I'm not sure you are getting my point.

Comment: @copper.hat, does the question look improved?